# Return more rows from FTSearch results using valuepicker in Extlib

Tags: dojo, xpages

I am using a valuepicker with dojoType: "extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch" from Extlib in my application. The dialog works fine and I can search for values. my problem is that the search only return 30 rows. I need to extend this to return more. is there a dojo setting I can use or any other way to return more rows?

[image]

```
<xe:formRow id="formRow5" label="Artikelnummer">
                    <xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox5"
                        displayLabel="true">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onBlur" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true"></xp:eventHandler></xe:djextListTextBox>
                    <xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker9"
                        for="djextListTextBox5" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch"
                        pickerText="Välj Artikel">
                        <xe:this.dataProvider>
                            <xe:dominoViewValuePicker
                                viewName="vProduktnr_xpages" labelColumn="xpdisplay"
                                searchType="ftSearch">
                            </xe:dominoViewValuePicker>
                        </xe:this.dataProvider>
                    </xe:valuePicker>
</xe:formRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the maxRowCount dojo attribute, as documented here http://www.seancull.co.uk/public/seancull.nsf/dx/getting-the-xpage-extension-library-name-pickers-to-show-more-than-50-names.htm

Comment: that page is not found, but I will try the maxRowCount

Comment: "maxRowCount" and "dojo attribute" are the essential parts of the answer

Comment: I'm glad that worked. I came across a blog post I did where I had found it unimplemented. Looks like it's implemented for dominoViewValuePicker. It may not be implemented for simple searches or array / list / map picker data providers. Typically, those should not contain large sample datasets of similar data.